# Typed logic vs many-sorted logic

Tags: logic, terminology, type-theory

I am confused as to what is the difference between many-sorted logic and typed logic.

Are they the same thing? If not, what are the differences?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many-sorted first-order logic is exactly the same thing as first-order logic over a simple type theory without any type constructors. You may want to look into the first four chapters Jacobs' book *Categorical logic and type theory* to see how it plays out exactly.

Chapter 4 of that book describes predicate logic over simple type theory, and when you remove all the simple type constructors then you arguably get exactly many-sorted first-order logic. The only difference is maybe one of presentation. In the type theoretical version formulas with free variables will always appear together with a context $x:A,y:B,...$ which declares the sorts of the variables. In other presentations it might be that you have a different stock of variables for each sort, so that they do not have to be explicitly declared. The deductive system in Jacobs book is a sequent calculus. Classical logic books typically use an axiomatic system, or maybe natural deduction. But the theorems which you can prove are the same.